# Why is the hash rate on my Mac higher than my PC with Antminer U2

Tags: asic, bfgminer

I just got my Antminer U2 and I've tried it on my PC and Macbook Pro. When Using my Macbook Pro with Asteroid, it shows a Hash rate of +3.0 GH/s. When I use BFGMiner on my PC, I'm only getting 2.07 GH/s. The BFGMiner is using the OC command also, and the Asteroid wasn't using anything. It it just displaying incorrectly or is there an actual difference?